# How do I insert a variable into a string using schemachange?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using schemachange (https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange) to manage creating resources in snowflake. I have an initial script that sets up, among other things, a stage. In schemachange, you can use variables with {{ ENV }} (as example). In the case below, I want to provide a url that uses {{ ENV }} as art of the string. i.e.

```
create stage if not exists test_{{ ENV }}
file_format = (type=json)
copy_options = (match_by_column_name=case_insensitive)
url='s3://test-bucket-{{ ENV }}-xxxxxxx/'
storage_integration = s3_int_{{ DBVERSION }};
```

The URL line is where I want to reference a bucket name specific to the ENV variable that's being passed in. I'm not sure how to do it in this case, tried just using the above but it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I am not very sure on this, but did you tried moving {{ ENV }} out of quotes. url='s3://test-bucket-'{{ ENV }}'-xxxxxxx/'. If its a python script, perhaps try using + operator for concatenation - 's3://test-bucket-'+{{ ENV }}+'-xxxxxxx/'

Comment: @pankaj I appreciate your response and sorry for the delay. This also doesn't seem to work, still trying to puzzle this through. It makes the substitution in the scenario above, just doesn't actually concatenate together so it ends up 's3://test-bucket-' + dev + '-xxxxxxx/'

Comment: But seems you are getting back value of {{ENV}} replaced (as dev). Did you tried without + operator too, i.e. keep {{ENV}} out of quotes?  url='s3://test-bucket-'{{ ENV }}'-xxxxxxx/'

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
CREATE STAGE IF NOT EXISTS Test
    URL = 's3://test-bucket-{{env}}'
```

In your schemachange command, you need to make sure you include -- vars command:

```
--vars '{"env":"MyEnvironment"}'
```

We have this running thru Azure DevOps pipelines and works great so far.